# Retrieve streaming data from API using Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, cloud, streaming

I want to stream real time data from Twitter API to Cloud Storage and BigQuery. I have to ingest and transform the data using Cloud Functions but the problem is I have no idea how to pull data from Twitter API and ingest it into the Cloud.

I know I also have to create a scheduler and a Pub/Sub topic to trigger Cloud Functions. I have created a Twitter developer account. The main problem is actually streaming the data into Cloud Storage.

I'm really new to GCP and streaming data so it'll be nice to see a clear explanation on this. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out which GCP service to use? Twitter released a toolkit recently for streaming to GCP: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/developer-guide--twitter-api-toolkit-for-google-cloud1
It's fairly complex IMO and the documentation is lacking but I plan on using cloud run with scheduler for streaming the tweets to pubsub and then using another scheduler job + another cloud run container to pull the pub sub messages and load to bigquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to design first your solution. What do you want to achieve? Streaming or Microbatches?

If streaming, you have to use the streaming API of Twitter. In short, you initiate a connection and you stay up and running (and connected) receiving the data.

If batches, you have to query an API and to download a set of message. In a Query-response mode.

---

That being said, how to implement it with Google Cloud. Streaming is problematic because you have to be always connected. And with serverless product you have timeout concern (9 minutes for Cloud Functions V1, 60 minutes for Cloud Run and Cloud Functions V2).

However you can imagine to invoke regularly your serverless product, stay connected for a while (let say 1h) and schedule trigger every hour.

Or use a VM to do that (or a pod on a K8S container)

---

You can also consider microbatches where you invoke every minute your Cloud Functions and to get all the messages for the past minutes.

---

At then end, all depends on your use case. What's the real time that you expect? which product do you want to use?

Comment: I want to do streaming but how do I initiate a connection between the API and Cloud? Do I need to write codes to programmatically initiate a connection and where do I put the codes in cloud functions?

Comment: Yes, you have to write code to initiate the connection. And you have to deploy that code according to the connection duration that you want (and the cost and maintenance effort that you want to do).